# Linux password expiring and cron jobs failing

Tags: cron, login, password

I have jobs running on a server which I access via powerbroker (so don't know the password).  However the password of the user account expired recently and the said jobs failed.

Due to password policy I don't think I will be able to get a non-expiring password for this account and updating the password monthly for an account only used to run cron jobs seems a bit of a waste.

Therefore I was wondering if there is any option to have a user account that can't be accessed using a password but can be logged into using other methods such as ssh keys or via powerbroker?

Thanks,
Ande

Comment: I think you're saying there's a user on machine X which has an expired password, and on machine X, their cronjobs are now failing?  In which case, ask to have the pam.d config for cron changed so that expired passwords don't prevent cron jobs running.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Hi Tony, Thanks for the prompt response and sorry for the delay in getting back to you!  Yes I was looking for someway to have an account which would continue to run cron jobs when the password expired.

Comment: Why would cron jobs be dependent on the password?

Comment: @EightBitTony Any hints on how to so change the pam config for cron?

Comment: @ADTC It seems to be the default configuration, for RHEL at least, that instantiation of a cron job goes through PAM and fails if the password is expired.